# Flow Button Bar error: [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow

I am using the **Flow Button Bar** component on my screen flow.
I am using the **Navigation** Action mode but when I click the button, I always get an exception:

> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.

Any help with how this can be resolved?

[image]

Comment: What version of the flow screen components from unofficial sf are you using?  Looking at this component, other people have had this problem as well, so it's good to make sure you're using the latest version.  https://unofficialsf.com/flow-button-bar-new-and-improved/

Comment: I am using the latest version to date and also left my comment there.